# Angular js - Using Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

Menu-Controller:

```
// Left Menu Start
'use strict';
 angular.module("MainApp")
   .controller('LeftMenuCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, actionCall) {

    $scope.notify = {};
    $scope.actionUrlCall = function(action)
    {
        actionCall.actionUrlCall(action, function(response){
            $scope.notify = actionCall.notify;
            console.log($scope.notify);
        });
    };
});
```

Now there are several html pages in view:

Each one of them has these notification directives:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <notification type="success"></notification>
    <notification type="error"></notification>
    <notification type="warning"></notification>
</div>
```

Which displays the notification as per the output from actionCall service.

I have console logged `console.log($scope.notify);` and I'm getting the required result. Problem is I don't know how to communicate this with the directives present on various different pages with different controllers and different scope.

Comment: Have you thought about using     $broadcast ?

Comment: @olu:  Any brief example would be nice to give me a head-start. Thanks

Comment: use $rootScope.$broadcast in your controller to broadcast the event across your app. use $rootScope.on in your directive to register the event.

Comment: @olu:  Nice. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is how I finally solved the issue.

1. I created a new service(menu-service.js) :

   ```
   'use strict';
   angular.module("MainApp")
   .factory('menuClick', function($rootScope) {
   var sharedService = {};
   sharedService.notify = {};

      sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
       this.broadcastItem();
   };
      sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
       $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
   };
      return sharedService;
   });
   ```
2. Then I injected my service which is named as menuClick in my menu controller and added some lines in it:

   ```
    angular.module("MainApp")

   .controller('LeftMenuCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, menuClick) {
       $scope.handleMenuClick = function(action) {
       menuClick.notify.warningNotify =  true;
       menuClick.notify.errorNotify =  true;
       menuClick.notify.successNotify =  true;
       if(!action.IsEnabled)
       {
           menuClick.notify.warningNotify = false;
           menuClick.notify.warningMessage = "This operation is disabled ( "+action.Text+" )";
           menuClick.prepForBroadcast(menuClick.notify);
       }
       };
      });
   ```
3. Then I injected menuClick to the controllers where I needed to listen the Broadcast data and added following lines in those controllers:

   ```
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.notify = menuClick.notify;
    });
   ```

And it started working!!